# Passing View as Command Parameter in WPF.Does it violet MVVM approach?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have data grid and there some number of columns in it.There are number of rows. I want to show one window when user clicks on the context menu of that row.I need first columns value in viewmodel from that row for some logic.Currently I am passing placement target as command parameter i.e.gridviewrow. Following is my code

```
<telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
                                        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" ></Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">

                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ContextMenu>
                                                    <MenuItem Header="show Window" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.ShowChart,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu, Mode=FindAncestor}}" CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"></MenuItem>


                                                </ContextMenu>
                                            </Setter.Value>


                                        </Setter>

                                    </Style>
                                </telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
```

How can I pass value of first column of particular row on which user has clicked?

Does it violet MVVM approach?What is solution if it violets MVVM approach in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Teoretically yes, because the only way to access the view is by INotifyPropertyChanged and IErrorDataInfo. However, it depends what do you inttend to do. If you want to change the visibilty of a UI elemnt, I violet the MVVM pattern because the other way arround it seems to complicated to me. I suggest to tell what exactly do you want to do, and maybe I will be able to help you :)

Comment: Thanks.I have datagrid and there are number of records in it. I am showing a context menu for each row.Each row has some number of columns. When user click on context menu,I  need a parameter  from first column for that particular row in viewmodel.So I am sending placement target.So I get a whole row and then I am extracting a particular column's value from it.

Comment: Hang on for 2 hours. I have a sampel at home an I will post it here :)

Comment: All done. Thank you for voting up my answer, and if you find it useful you please don't hesitate to aprove the next one. This way it will stays on top for more people who may need it. In addition, I could use some reputation :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can try to create a new ViewModel class for the grid's rows and each column is a property of the ViewModel. So you can easily bind the data context of the row to that ViewModel and the columns to its properties.

Answer (score 0):

I will post another answer since you edited masively the question.

If you use a datagrid in your view, the your view (XAML code) should look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="CareerTrackWpfClient.Views.User_Main_Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="User_Main_Window" Background="Black">
<Window> 
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="gridbooks">
            <DataGrid Height="650" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="BooksGrid" RowHeight="90" ColumnWidth="200" 
                  ColumnHeaderHeight="40" HeadersVisibility="Column" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="DarkGray" 
                  AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" BorderBrush="Gray" 
                  BorderThickness="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Book #" Width="220" Binding="{Binding BookID}" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Book Title" Width="220" Binding="{Binding Title}" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

You should have a model like this

```
public class Book
{
     public int BookID {get; set;}
     public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

Now, either you do a ViewModel where you fill the list (like Zarzan said) - and this way you will respect the MVVM pattern. Or in the code beheind, in the constructor, bellow the InitializeComponent() method, you write something like this

```
List<Book> booksProvider=new List<Book>();
booksProvider.Add(new Book{BookID=1,"Book 1"}) ;
booksProvider.Add(new Book{BookID=2,"Book 2"}) ;
gridbooks.ItemsSource=booksProvider;
```

Is very nice using this UI component (DataGrid), from my point of view. It has the validations on place. Try to enter strings on the BookID field, and it will notify you. It is very flexible and you don't have to install anything.

Hope it helps as many developers as possible.